# what is the meaning of-"_nfpb"="true" in url?

Tags: random

I am using

```
"_nfpb=true"
```

in my url. But don't know the meaning of it. Can some please explain to me what does it stand for? Please be generous and go on easy terms?

Comment: Depends on application. Did You tried to [google it](https://community.oracle.com/thread/2071684?start=0&tstart=0)?

Comment: yes but found nothing useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> `_nfpb` stand for `"NetUI framework Post Back"`

The `_nfpb=true` parameter is used by the portal framework to reload the portal state upon accessing the postback `URL`. It displays in the `URL` and causes the framework to load an existing state from a session or cookie."

But remember that a specific parameter means is totally dependent on the **concrete application**, there's no general standard that everyone has to use.

Comment: Thanks for your effort but what does it mean?

Comment: @user2719152 What do you don't understand?